# Angular application freezes when assigning an object to a variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object

I'm having strong performance issues when assigning an object to a variable.

The object only has 5 properties. I know this assignment of the object is the issue because when I commented out the line of code for the variable assignment, performance had no issues.

Here is what the object looks like.

[image]

The only possible issue might be the array of similar locations. 2236 location objects are in this array. Here is what one location object looks like.

[image]

The object isn't that large. Any idea why my app pretty much acts like its in a constant loop when trying to assign this variable?

Here is where I assign the variable in my angular controller.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.components')
    .controller('UploadLocationsDuplicatesModalController',
      UploadLocationsDuplicatesModalController);

  UploadLocationsDuplicatesModalController.$inject = [
    '$scope',
    '$q',
    '$modalInstance',
    'campaignsService',
    'customersService',
    'locationsService',
    'segmentsService',
    'sublistsService',
    'campaign',
    'customer',
    'list',
    'locations',
    'options'
  ];

  /* @ngInject */
  function UploadLocationsDuplicatesModalController(
    $scope,
    $q,
    $modalInstance,
    campaignsService,
    customersService,
    locationsService,
    segmentsService,
    sublistsService,
    campaign,
    customer,
    list,
    locations,
    options
  ) {
    // Non scope variables.
    var modalVm = this;

    // Scope variables. 
    modalVm.locations = locations; // <----- Assigning the object here
```

Comment: I receive zero errors in the developers console.

Comment: Is `modalVm.locations` used in the view (html)? If so, please share that code too.